# Disabled When Lacking Input in Field in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have set of inputs that needs to be filled out completely. I should disable the submit button when its not complete. Its working fine until I decided to erase and fill it out again.
It never disables. What would be the proper and correct way to do this? Is there a better way to do this?

[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/verification-code-input-forked-zxell?file=/src/index.js)

```
   <div className="App">
      <InputCode
        length={6}
        label="Code Label"
        loading={loading}
        onComplete={(code) => {
          setCodes(code);
          setLoading(true);
          setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 10000);
        }}
      />
      <br />
      <button disabled={codes?.length < 6 || !codes}>Submit</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To do that, you would instead get disabled state from your child:**

- Adding a new state to your parent component:

```
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
```

- Pass it down to your child component:

```
<InputCode
        length={6}
        label="Code Label"
        loading={loading}
        onComplete={(code) => {
          setLoading(true);
          setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 10000);
        }}
        setDisabled={setDisabled}
/>
```

- Set the status of your button base on that state:

```
<button disabled={disabled}>Submit</button>
```

- Import setDisabled ot your child component and add useEffect like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (code.some((num) => num === "")) {
      setDisabled(true);
    } else {
      setDisabled(false);
    }
  }, [code, setDisabled]);
```

---

[Working Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/verification-code-input-forked-qewjq)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add new method to check whether the inputs are filled or not like you have for **onComplete**

inputCode.js

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react"; //add useEffect to watch code values
const InputCode = ({ length, label, loading, onComplete, onInComplete }) //onIncomplete
```

Add watcher to code and execute onIncomplete until the values of inputs are equal to length given to component

```
useEffect(() => {
  const values = code.filter((item) => {
    return item !== "";
   });
   if (values.length !== length) {
     onInComplete(true);
   }
}, [code]);
```

in index.js

```
<InputCode
  length={6}
  label="Code Label"
  loading={loading}
  onComplete={(code) => {
    setCodes(code);
    setLoading(true);
    setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 1000);
  }}
  onInComplete={() => setCodes(false)} //add this props to check validation
  />
```

and you can simply disable button based on code state

```
<button disabled={!codes}>Submit</button>
```